# Need help in modifying existing regex pattern in python to not include last word in pattern searching

Tags: python, regex

I need help in modifying existing regex pattern to not include the last word in pattern searching.

Currently, this is the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tZRR8Y/1) pattern I have `.*\w(?=\s+\w+-)` and this is the input string:

```
 13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt ldf-dfdlj-dfldjf-dfs test
```

Now, this pattern returns the match which is expected:

```
 13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt
```

But, I have another scenario, where my input string is:

```
 13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt ldf-dfdlj-dfldjf-dfs test-test
```

Now, my expected match is

```
 13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt
```

But I am getting

```
 13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt ldf-dfdlj-dfldjf-dfs
```

So now, basically I want to modify the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/TEBqOy/1) pattern which will basically ignore the last word in sentence during pattern search. Kindly guide me on this.

Comment: It looks to me you want `^.*?\w-\w+` or `^.*?\w(?:-\w+)+`. I.e. everything from the start till the first hyphenated word (including it). You should include the exact pattern requirements, creating regex from example strings will take long time and many irrelevant solutions along the way.

Comment: You are saying, _"... to not include the last word ..."_.  Isn't the last word, _"test"_?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with an addition of negative lookahead condition inside the already existing lookahead condition:

```bash
.*\w(?=\s+\w+-(?!\w+$))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZRR8Y/2)

Negative lookahead condition `(?!\w+$)` will make sure to ignore last word in a line after matching a hyohen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capture group, and define a pattern which excludes the values.

For example, this pattern will capture every value up to the last word, or hyphenated words.

```
(.+)\s+\w+(?:-\w+)*$
```

Although, you are implying that it should exclude the last word, and the second to last word.

So, you can modify the pattern to include an additional match, at the end.

```
(.+)(?:\s+\w+(?:-\w+)*){2}$
```

Here is an example.

```py
string_a = '13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt ldf-dfdlj-dfldjf-dfs test'
string_b = '13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt ldf-dfdlj-dfldjf-dfs test-test'

pattern = re.compile(r'(.+)(?:\s+\w+(?:-\w+)*){2}$')

match = re.match(pattern, string_a)
print(match.group(1))

match = re.match(pattern, string_b)
print(match.group(1))
```

Output

```
13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt
13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt
```